# API returns 404 to Retrofit

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, retrofit

I have an [API](http://localpro.herokuapp.com/api/test/drink/) which returns a simple JSON response just fine (Response code 200). But when I request the same URL from my android app, it gets 404.

Here are the dependencies

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:2.0.0-beta2'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.6.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:converter-gson:2.0.0-beta2'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4'
```

This is my interface

```
public interface ExampleApi {
    @GET("/test/drink/")
    Call<Example> getExample();
}
```

These codes are running in the MainActivity

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl("https://localpro.herokuapp.com/api")
    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
    .build();

ExampleApi api = retrofit.create(ExampleApi.class);
Call<Example> call = api.getExample();
call.enqueue(new Callback<Example>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Response<Example> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
        try {
            Log.i("Response code", " " + response.code());
            Log.i("Response", " " + response.body().toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
    }
});
```

Log

```
12-11 16:59:44.235 8885-8885/com.wealthpack.retrofitfinal I/Response code:  404 
12-11 16:59:44.236 8885-8885/com.wealthpack.retrofitfinal W/System.err: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference 
12-11 16:59:44.236 8885-8885/com.wealthpack.retrofitfinal W/System.err:     at com.wealthpack.retrofitfinal.MainActivity$1.onResponse(MainActivity.java:45) 
12-11 16:59:44.236 8885-8885/com.wealthpack.retrofitfinal W/System.err:     at retrofit.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallback$1.run(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:86)
12-11 16:59:44.236 8885-8885/com.wealthpack.retrofitfinal W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746) 
12-11 16:59:44.236 8885-8885/com.wealthpack.retrofitfinal W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
12-11 16:59:44.236 8885-8885/com.wealthpack.retrofitfinal W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
12-11 16:59:44.236 8885-8885/com.wealthpack.retrofitfinal W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443) 
12-11 16:59:44.236 8885-8885/com.wealthpack.retrofitfinal W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
12-11 16:59:44.236 8885-8885/com.wealthpack.retrofitfinal W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
12-11 16:59:44.236 8885-8885/com.wealthpack.retrofitfinal W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
```

**Note:** I'm completely new to Android development and using Java after a few years.

Comment: Check if you android device is  in the same network of your localhost server, the problem is because you app can't find this url, and will get 404 not found.

Comment: The API is not on localhost. It's on the Internet. @diogojme

Comment: The url is working and the path `/test/drink/` looks right and the problem seems to be that you are getting an `"java.lang.NullPointerException"` in `response.body().toString()` caused by null body, I tested in my application sample and it works, the 404 not found is about invalid URL or Path, make sure you are calling the right URL.

Comment: I know that the "NullPointerException" is caused by the null body. I just need to know how the URL can be invalid. I provided both the baseURL and the endpoint in the question. Can you please send me a link to the code of your working sample application? @diogojme

Comment: Yes, i will post in a few minutes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a syntax problem,

you have to write your service like this:

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl("https://localpro.herokuapp.com/api/")
    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
    .build();

public interface ExampleApi {
@GET("test/drink/")
Call<Example> getExample();
```

for more details check this nice presentation from Jake Wharton https://youtu.be/KIAoQbAu3eA?t=32m24s :)

Answer (score 0):

To request your service

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Response response = App.retrofit().buildRequest(TestActivity.this).universityService().getExample(); //getExample("json")
        if(response.getStatus() == 200){
            System.out.println(response.getBody().toString());
        }else{
            System.out.println(response.getStatus());
        }
    }
}).start();
```

To get your service

```
@GET("/test/drink/")
Response getExample();
```

or

```
@GET("/test/drink/")
Response getExample(@Query("format") String format);
```

Your models

```
public class Example {
    public boolean success;
    public List<Drink> drinks;
}

public class Drink {
    public String name;
    public String description;
}
```

Retrofit adapter, im using 1.9.0 version of retrofit

```
private static final String url = "http://localpro.herokuapp.com/api";

restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setEndpoint(url)
            .build();
```

This works for me.

Comment: I wanted an answer for the retrofit:2.0.0-beta2 version.